# How to load part of HTML from URL even after clicking event?

Tags: swift, parsing, swift3, xml-parsing, hybrid-mobile-app

I have wrote some code to load all html from url and parse it to remove header. So I got the rest of the html under header to show.
However, after clicking event in the body html, the screen shows full html from the URL.

Is there any solution for this? or Did I make a mistake to approach this problem?

The code I made is below

```
import UIKit
import Fuzi

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURLString = "http://yahoo.com"
        var myHTMLString = ""
        guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
            print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
            return
        }

        do {
            myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }

        do {
            // if encoding is omitted, it defaults to NSUTF8StringEncoding
            let doc = try! HTMLDocument(string: myHTMLString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let fullHtml:String = (doc.firstChild(xpath: "//*")?.rawXML)!


            if let header = doc.firstChild(xpath: "//body/div/header") {

                let headerString:String = header.rawXML

                let withoutHeader = fullHtml.replacingOccurrences(of: headerString, with: "")

                webView.loadHTMLString(withoutHeader as String, baseURL: nil)
            }
        } catch let error{
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works with UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked. You can modify it to use with other UIWebViewNavigationType.

```
import UIKit
import Fuzi

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.delegate = self

    let myURLString = "http://yahoo.com"
    var myHTMLString = ""
    guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
        print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
        return
    }

    do {
        myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    do {
        // if encoding is omitted, it defaults to NSUTF8StringEncoding
        let doc = try! HTMLDocument(string: myHTMLString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let fullHtml:String = (doc.firstChild(xpath: "//*")?.rawXML)!


        if let header = doc.firstChild(xpath: "//body/div/header") {

            let headerString:String = header.rawXML

            let withoutHeader = fullHtml.replacingOccurrences(of: headerString, with: "")

            webView.loadHTMLString(withoutHeader as String, baseURL: nil)
        }
    } catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == .linkClicked
    {
        let myURLString = webView.request?.url.absoluteString
        webView.stopLoading()
        var myHTMLString = ""
        let myURL = URL(string: myURLString)
    do {
        myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    do {
        // if encoding is omitted, it defaults to NSUTF8StringEncoding
        let doc = try! HTMLDocument(string: myHTMLString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let fullHtml:String = (doc.firstChild(xpath: "//*")?.rawXML)!


        if let header = doc.firstChild(xpath: "//body/div/header") {

            let headerString:String = header.rawXML

            let withoutHeader = fullHtml.replacingOccurrences(of: headerString, with: "")

            webView.loadHTMLString(withoutHeader as String, baseURL: nil)
        }
    } catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: what I add basically is when a link is clicked inside the webview, the webview stops the request and get the url of the request, then parse the html from the url to remove header and then pass it into the webview again.

Comment: But It doesn't show url. When I print variable **myURLString**, It shows **Optional("about:blank")**

Comment: Try again. I changed webview.stoploading() after getting the url

Comment: This is weird. When I click a button link made with href it shows empty and also When I click a button link made with onclick It doesn't print but shows some log **2017-05-25 19:59:02.988030+0900 test2[2088:374544] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2017-05-25 19:59:02.988129+0900 test2[2088:374544] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO**

Comment: Because the navigation type is not .linkClicked, you will have to try it with other navigation type.

Comment: oh I see I will look for the others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer!

Thanks to @Sherman for the hint to solve this problem.

I had to replace a line of code below

```
if navigationType == .linkClicked
```

to

```
if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked
```

Then It works!